# sorting an orderedMap by a specific key in Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, immutable.js

Please check this [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/lau_chung/1c2hww9h/2/)

How can I sort an `orderedMap` object by the keys `sequence` in a descending order? I know there is a `sortBy` method but the [document](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap/sortBy) doesn't give a clearer example.

Here's my original object:

```
var props = {
  "item": {
    "A": {
      "sequence": 5
    },
    "B": {
      "sequence": null
    },
    "C":{
      "sequence": 2
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like the result to be like:

```
var props = {
  "item": {
    "A": {
      "sequence": 5
    },
    "C":{
      "sequence": 2
    },
    "B": {
      "sequence": null
    }
  }
}
```

Example Code:

```
var data = Immutable.fromJS(props,(key, value)=>{
     var isIndexed = Immutable.Iterable.isIndexed(value);
     return isIndexed ? value.toList() :value.toOrderedMap();
});

var sorted = data.get('item').sortBy((item) => item.get('sequence'));

console.log(sorted.toJS())
```

Comment: [Javascript Objects are unordered by definition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069705/2260614), after `toJS()` the sort order is in a few cases maintained but not always.

Answer (score 11):

The function you are providing to `sortBy()` is comparator and it needs to return a Number. By adding a minus in front of the `item.get('sequence')` or following the result with `reverse()` you will reverse the sort, getting you the output that you want.

Here's an example:

```
var sorted = data.get('item').sortBy((item) => -item.get('sequence'));
// or var sorted = data.get('item').sortBy((item) => item.get('sequence')).reverse();
// you can now use .map() to go through your OrderedMap which has been
// sortbed by the sequence property and would look like your desired output
```

Note that you are working with an OrderedMap and that simply calling `sorted.toJS()` would return a regular JS object where the keys are, obviously, not sorted.

```
// If you need to iterate through the map and return some 
// plain JS you can do something like:
sorted.map(x => x.get('sequence')).toJS()
// => Object {A: 5, C: 2, B: null}
```